# Finding specific class in HTML using C# and getting its value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, parsing

I'm trying to download an entire HTML page like following:

```
var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://mypage.com/");
```

and this HTML document contains a class like this:

```
<span class="mem_loc">United States</span>
```

Like this literally...

I need to find somehow now this class mem_loc and it's value , which is United states or any other country...

Is there any "easy" way that this could be done in C# ?

P.S. The structure of the Tag is always like this , so I can probably search it through the string or somehow?

P.S. I want to fetch only whats between > < values, which is a country name...

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to use an HTML parser. For example [`HTML agility pack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is one such tool. It allows you to do this:

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='mem_loc']"));
```

Comment: good suggestion, can this be done with using just regular regex, without any external library? =)

Comment: Yes, it can be done using regular regex. You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454. And once you have read this answer you can get back to HTML Agility Pack or a similar HTML parsing tool.

Comment: Darin cool ty, what'cha think which way is better? I mean adding an entire new library just because of 1 line of code isn't a very good idea no  ?

Comment: Darin hahahh that was a good one :D ... Okay I understand it now better =D

Comment: There's a difference between *1 line of code*, and *code that works in production*. So it will all depend on your scenario. If you want to be mocking something real quick for a presentation or a dummy website then of course you can use a regex. But if you want to write code that works in a production system then believe me, you don't want to be using regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: Darin, yes sir understood it clearly! Your reputation amount tells me quite a lot about you ,and you sir deserve a big respect! Thanks for all the advices =)